# LDAP plugin that is compatible with SonarQube 3.7.4?

Tags: plugins, ldap, sonarqube

Is there a version of the LDAP plugin that is compatible with SonarQube 3.7.4.

When I go to the SonarQube Update Center for available plugins, it tells me the last version 1.4 of LDAP plugin is not compatible, requires SonarQube upgrade.

We would like to continue use of SonarQube 3.7.4, does anyone know if an older version of LDAP plugin would work with SonarQube 3.7.4?

Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have your constraint but I could not recommend you enough to upgrade to latest LTS version instead of continuing using such an old version.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the older versions of the ldap plugin here - http://downloads.sonarsource.com/plugins/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-ldap-plugin/

I couldn't find the release notes associated with these versions, but you can give 1.3 and 1.2 a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use version 1.3. Here is commit with upgrade to API 3.0: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-ldap/commit/5aaf28bcb20482970140a57fca92893fc761d4a1

Download: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-ldap-plugin/1.3/